# Node ::date doesn't convert timestamp without zone

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date

I am trying to format timestamp so it only returns date and not time like `year-dd-mm`.

I formatted like this `u.registered::date` where u.registered is timestamp without timezone.

In psql, I tested it and does return date format but on the server side it still returns timestamp format.

When I use `db.get_mypage` query on pgadmin it shows like this.

[image]

But on node when I console.log it displays
[image]

Node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cors = require('cors');
var massive = require('massive');
var config = require('./config');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

var db = massive.connect({connectionString: config.connectionString}, function(err, localdb){
    db = localdb;
    app.set('db', db);

});


app.get('/mypage/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    db.get_mypage([req.params.id], function(err, individual) {
        console.log(individual);
        if(err) res.status(500).send(err);
        else res.send(individual);
    })
})


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("I am listening");
})
```

db.get_mypage

```
 select u.user_id, b.book_id, u.username, b.title, b.pages, u.registered::date 
 from mypage as m
 join users u on u.user_id = m.user_id
 join book b on b.book_id = m.book_id
 where u.user_id = $1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is in the database. The PgAdmin display suggests that the database is producing a real `date` value so that's fine. The problem looks like the value from the database is being converted to a native JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). But `Date`s are actually full timestamps and the time-of-day portion of a `Date` defaults to 00:00:00:

```
> new Date(2017, 4, 10).toISOString()
  "2017-05-10T07:00:00.000Z"
> new Date('2017-04-10').toISOString()
  "2017-04-10T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Looks like your library is using the `new Date(y, m, d)` form of the `Date` constructor.

There is no date-without-time-of-day in JavaScript so you might need to work with strings instead. You could use [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) in the query to get an ISO8601 date string:

```
select ..., to_char(u.registered, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

That should give you better control over what timezone is applied. Or you could make sure the local timezone for your application is UTC so that you can only worry about timezone issues at the very edges of your application (i.e. display and input).

Answer (score 1):

The reson is that **pg** (the engine used by **massive**) by default converts *date*, *timestamp without time zone* and *timestamp with time zone* to native JavaScript Date objects. But the native Date object don't separate date and time. The new Temporal object will do that, but it is at stage 3 at the time of this writing.

You can make pg return fields of type *date* and *timestamp without time zone* as strings by changing the type parser:

```
import pg from 'pg';

pg.types.setTypeParser(pg.types.builtins.DATE, (d) => d);
pg.types.setTypeParser(pg.types.builtins.TIMESTAMP, (d) => d);
```

I don't know know if **massive** doses something extra, but hopefully you know what to look for.