# Using moment-timezone to display time AFTER being offset

Tags: format, momentjs, moment-timezone

How do I format a date/time from UTC into local time AFTER taking into consideration the time zone? I.e I don't want the data to display like this:

`2023-06-21 13:42:17 -04:00`

This has the offset data included. I want to calculate the offset and include it in the time itself. So I want this:

`2023-06-21 9:42:17`

I'm using a postgres db to store the current timestamp without time zone in UTC as default data like this:
`timezone('UTC'::text, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Then I use moment-timezone to change it to local time, with this code:

`let z = moment.utc('2023-06-21 13:42:17.839849', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').tz('America/Toronto').format()`

This gives me:
`2023-06-21T13:42:17-04:00`

I tried formatting this string various ways but this is one of the ways:

`let z = moment.utc(data[0].sent_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').tz('America/Toronto').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`

It gives me a date time in the specified format WITHOUT calculating the offset in the time:

`2023-06-21 13:42:17`

How do I make it so it display the time correctly taking into consideration the offset and not just ignoring it? Any suggestion would be appreciated. I've been searching for hours and none of the solutions on stack overflow or anywhere else could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the output format within the `.format()` function.

```js
let z = moment
  .utc('2023-06-21 13:42:17.839849', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
  .tz('America/Toronto')
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // 2023-06-21 09:42:17 

console.log(z)

// If you want 2023-06-21 9:42:17 without 0 before 9 remove a H from the string
let x = moment
  .utc('2023-06-21 13:42:17.839849', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
  .tz('America/Toronto')
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss'); // 2023-06-21 9:42:17 
  
console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.43/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AITheLazyMonkey for posting your solution. The way you formatted the timestamp and the way I did it in the the question was the same but yours worked! So I finally I realized that my problem was not formatting. The reason I'm not getting the correct local time is because I'm using nodejs, and the pg package - I found my problem and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74562880/14811503). This is how I understand it: when pg gets data from the db with a timestamp, it converts it into a JavaScript Date object and when it does, it thinks the data is in local time so it converts it to local time. So this is what I was getting when I console.log the data I get back and passing to moment:

```
2023-06-23T17:55:40.852Z
```

instead of this which is stored in postgres:

```
2023-06-23 13:55:40.852107
```

So I added this code to change the incoming timestamp data to a string:

```
const pg = require("pg")
const types = pg.types;
types.setTypeParser(1114, function (stringValue) {
return stringValue;
});
```

When I pass this into moment, it worked! Hope this will help someone who's having the same problem!